# Protect php script that receive paypal IPN notifications

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

In my website, I've integrated a php script that receive an IPN notification and send a license key to the customer. This script is in a folder with other 2 php files required by the php script... How can I protect this folder? If I place in it an `.htaccess` with:

```
order allow,deny
deny from all
```

I block the paypal notifications too.

How can I protect it? Do I need to?

Comment: I'm not sure everyone understands what you mean by "protect this folder". Do you want to deny listing of the contents of this folder? Or deny the public from executing the other two php files? Or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can safely limit access to your IPN script only to the following list of IP addresses:

```
216.113.188.202
216.113.188.203
216.113.188.204
66.211.170.66
```

This can be done in the following way:

```
if (!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],array('216.113.188.202','216.113.188.203','216.113.188.204','66.211.170.66')) {
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
exit();
}
```

In this way ONLY Paypal will be able to access the IPN script.

This list of IP address has been rather stable for years. In case if Paypal adds a new address, you can add reporting to email and review such cases manually.

Comment: Thanks!!!! There is any way to do the same thing but with the domain? In other words ... $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] return the ip address of the sender server ... and to get the remote domain?

Comment: Are the IPs the same for sandbox?  Could you elaborate on what to do if they add IPs?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer was posted in 2009, so the list is probably outdated. Check https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/92

Answer (score 3):

There are many things you can do:

1. Give your script an obscure name so that it is not easily guessable.
2. Disable directory listings in the folder
3. Check if the calling site is paypal.com (or related IP address etc.)

Comment: I'ev never do this ... to disable directory listing for all file in a folder I need to place an .htaccess in this folder with ... IndexIgnore *  ... it's right?

Comment: I've tryed with this but I receive an error 500 if I try to browse the php script!

Answer (score 3):

why you are trying to do this?

in IPN system, you first just bounce the variables that are passed to your ipn script back to paypal using cURL or fshock or what ever... looking into the response you can tell if it's a valid transaction or not... someone can not fake a transaction variable that does not exists in paypal itself... all they can do is to reuse an older transaction info again to fool your script.. since it exists on paypal your script will be assuming that it's a successfull payment...

so you can prevent this just by comparing txn_id against your database and if already exists in your database this means someone is trying to fool you using an already recorded transaction info...

since you do those checks who cares about the ones that call this ipn script... it wont be working for them since you check the variables against paypal and your database...

in any exceptions print out a nice sentence to tell them "This script is robust! Dont Try to fool us!"

Comment: +1 Exactly. You probably shouldn't be handling payments at all if you don't know how to do error handling or implement protocols according to specs.

Comment: Why add security at all?  It's only money.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the IP from which PayPal will use the script try:

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
allow from [Paypal-IP]
```

Comment: there isn't a way  to filter the domain instead of the ip address?

Comment: I've found! .. order deny, allow - deny from all - allow from .*paypal\.com.*

Comment: you can find the list of paypal related IP on this link : https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/92

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend shutting out all IPs, since you can't be sure that Paypal will keep the requests coming from the same IP all the time. If they ever decide to change their IP range, your setup will break, probably without notification to you.

I think the script that processes the Paypal request is the place to handle this - in that script you need to make sure that the request is actually coming from Paypal. You can do this by using some obscure URL that isn't easily guessed as has been suggested.

If at all possible, look into the shared secret setup for IPN - this way you have a better way of checking that the request is actually coming from Paypal, although it is a bit harder to set up.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've not setup the shared secret too ... now I check if the currency, the ammount and the business e-mail are right ... and then I would like check if the transaction ID is unique ... but to do this! I must setup a database where store the infos for all the transacions ... but I've never used database and I don't know how to!

Comment: Please "unknown (google)", don't be cross with me but don't you think that it wouldn't hurt to gain some experience with PHP, web and database programming before releasing things to public where real money is involved???

Comment: You are right! In fact i've not release and published nothing! My website is off-line!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the go live checklist:

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_golivechecklist

(Developer Home > How to > API > Go Live Checklist)

for a list of ip address to allow

Comment: This should get the check!  Thank you very much for this!  Favorited this article because of you.

Answer (score 1):

Now I've do this:

in the folder where is stored the php script and the 2 configuration files I've created an other folder where I moved the 2 config files and where I've placed a .htaccess with the following code:

```
order allow,deny
deny from all
```

Now the 2 config files have a good protection! ... but not the script that receive the notifications!
If I try to block the directory listing( for the folder that contains the php script and the config folder) with:

```
IndexIgnore *
```

The paypal sandbox gives me an error 500!

So the only thing that I can do to protect the script is to place, on the head of it, a condition that verify the notifications come from paypal.com ?

Finally I've added on head of the php script an if statement based on the remote host name:

```
 $remote_host = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

if someone is interested, it's also possible to query `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` but must be configured the httpd.conf file on the server.