# How to protect IPN listener from unwanted access?

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have just implemented a generic handler that listens requests from Paypal instant payment notification (IPN) service. It is working fine and getting me my required data. Now my concern is that I want this script to be called only by paypal IPN service and not anyone else.

I have seen a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123933/protect-php-script-that-receive-paypal-ipn-notifications) that lists the IPs used by Paypal and then verifies requests IP address with the list. But the problem is, the last may change sooner or later. Is there a durable solution to this problem?

Comment: I do not think that IP block is the right solution. For me the verification of IPN is what you must have, and together with PDT handler can secure your automatic transaction. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/

Comment: Also what a hacker can do, is to pay less than what you actually ask, and you have all the messages correctly and from paypal, except of amount. Do you have made check for that ? and situations like that ?

Comment: The security comes with the POST back to PayPal to verify that the data came from them.  If the IPN data verifies then you know it came from PayPal and you can process it as such.  If the IPN data returns as invalid then you know something could be up.  I like to save those as invalid so that I can review them.  As long as you don't automatically fully process orders that are invalid, though, you'll be fine.

Comment: If you're having to do any checks for amounts then you need to fix your payment process.  If using standard buttons, make sure you're using hosted buttons.  I always recommend the Express Checkout API if you have that level of programming skill.  A hosted button is enough, though, because it will hide all of the details of the payment so the user can't adjust it before submitting it.